# apply functions or operations on dataframe java which strips the last special character

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the data coming in for first column 'code' for dataframe as  below

> '101-23','23-00-11','NOV-11-23','34-000-1111-1'

and now i want to the values as below for 'code' column after the substring.

> 101,23-00,NOV-11,34-000-1111

The above can achieved easily by java code as below

```
String str ="23-00-11";    
int index=str.lastindex("-");
String ss=str.substring(0,index);
```

which gives

> '23-00'

How to do with dataframe and to write udf orapply to dataframe with    spark 1.6.2 java 1.8?
I tried with `df.withcolumn("code",substring("code",0,1))` but didnt find   the way to find the last index. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import *
      newDf = df.withColumn('_c0', regexp_replace('_c0', '@', ''))\
      .withColumn('_c1', regexp_replace('_c1', "'", ''))\
      .withColumn('_c2', regexp_replace('_c2', '!', ''))

    newDf.show()
```

**Updated**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df11 = Seq("'101-23','23-00-11','NOV-11-23','34-000-1111-1'").toDS()

df11.show()

//df11.select(col("a"), substring_index(col("value"), ",", 1).as("b"))
val df111=df11.withColumn("value", substring(df11("value"), 0, 10))
df111.show()
```

Result :

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|'101-23','23-00-1...|
+--------------------+

+----------+
|     value|
+----------+
|'101-23','|
+----------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df11: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]
df111: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Here I am talking about only one column called “code” which has values as above. More over the pyspark code with regexp_replace will replace with empty space as 101-23 to 10123 but required output would be 101 in this case and it will differ for other values. The characters after last special character (-) should be stripped and substring of code is require.

Comment: The value should be 101 as a result. And the end index should be calculated dynamically based on the value being passed. Here your solution has end index as 10. How to calculate the end index and pass to the Substring.